# How do I configure PDFBox to print this type of character correctly?

Tags: java, pdfbox

As-is, this code (on a Windows PC running JVM 8) prints an unwanted BOM (þÿ) at the beginning of the line, and the "-" that should appear between 'testing' and 'PDF' is a space.

I'm sure this is related to UTF-16 vs. UTF-8 and that I probably need to set the encoding in PDFBox. There are some posts about this sort of thing but many of them are quite old and don't look reliable (and I freely admit to not being familiar with PDFBox and only marginally so with UTF-x). Thank you.

```
package com.canchek.report;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.COSVisitorException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.edit.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;

public class PdfBoxTest {

    /* PDFBox coordinate system starts in the bottom LEFT
     */


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, COSVisitorException {
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage();
        document.addPage(page);
        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);

        PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;
        contentStream.setFont(font, 20);

        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(20, 700);
        contentStream.drawString("testing\u2013PDF");
        contentStream.endText();

        contentStream.close();
        document.save("C:/temp/test.pdf");

        document.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Please update to 2.0.7 instead of whatever you're using now. That one works.

Comment: Some are described in https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/migration.html . I suggest you delete the question or answer it yourself. Additional tip: If you want to use different fonts and embed subsets, get them with `PDType0Font.load(document, new File("c:/windows/fonts/ArialUni.ttf"));`.